# Perl file test operator help

Tags: perl

This is a really basic issue, but I'm new to perl and cannot work out what the issue is. I'm just trying to isolate the files in a directory, but the -d operator keeps treating all the folder contents as files ...

@contents is my array, and when I run this:

```
use strict;

if ($ARGV[1]) {
    die("Error: You can only monitor one directory at a time\n");
}

my $directory = $ARGV[0] || die "Error: No directory defined\n";

opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Error: Can't open dir $directory: $!";
my @contents = readdir(DIR);

foreach my $item(@contents) {
    if (-d $item) { next; }
    print"$item is a file\n"; 
}

closedir (DIR);
```

I keep getting both folders and files. Alternatively, if I use -f, I get nothing.

edit: this is the output -

```
file01.txt is a file
folder 01  is a file
folder 02 is a file
Screen shot 2010-04-18 at 1.26.17 PM.png is a file
```

I'm running this on OSX

edit:dir `ls -l` output:

```
aaron ~/Documents/test: ls -l
total 112
-rw-r--r--@ 1 aaron  staff  51235 18 Apr 13:26 Screen shot 2010-04-18 at 1.26.17 PM.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 aaron  staff      7 18 Apr 13:26 file01.txt
drwxr-xr-x  3 aaron  staff    102 18 Apr 13:25 folder 01
drwxr-xr-x  2 aaron  staff     68 18 Apr 13:25 folder 02
```

Comment: I've updated the full program. Still no luck with the below suggestions.

Comment: Your program works perfectly fine on my machine. And I guess its working fine on yours too as `.` and `..` are not appearing in the **full** output, which shows the scripts is bypassing dir. Looks like `folder 01` is a file.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that . and .. weren't coming up. But 'folder 01' is definitely a folder. Just an empty folder made in finder. As is 'folder 02'.

Comment: Are you sure its not a **link** to a folder. Because in your script you are assuming every **non-dir** as a file. Please do a `ls -l` on the directory you pass to the script and paste it.

Comment: @unicornaddict: It is relative pathnames - Aaron is not testing on '.' like you and I were but on some other directory.  When I test his script on '..', my current directory shows up as a 'file'...and the '-f' fails because the name doesn't exist in my current directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution

I was testing with '.' as the directory...you're testing with some other directory.  The names read from the directory are then checked relative to the current directory.  If I use some other directory name, I'll get almost everything except '.' and '..' listed as files, regardless.

If you prefix the name with the value of $ARGV[0], you'll get the expected result:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;

if ($ARGV[1]) {
    die("Error: You can only monitor one directory at a time\n");
}

my $directory = $ARGV[0] || die "Error: No directory defined\n";

opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Error: Can't open dir $directory: $!";
my @contents = readdir(DIR);

foreach my $item(@contents) {
    next if -d "$ARGV[0]/$item";
    print "$ARGV[0]/$item is a file\n"; 
}

closedir (DIR);
```

#### Previous attempts to explain

This works on MacOS X:

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @contents = <*>;

foreach my $item (@contents)
{
    print "== $item\n";
    next if -d $item;
    print "$item is a file\n";
}
```

Test:

```
MiniMac JL: perl -c xx.pl
xx.pl syntax OK
MiniMac JL: perl xx.pl
== cproto-4.7g
== fpqsort1
fpqsort1 is a file
== fpqsort1.h
fpqsort1.h is a file
== fpqsort2
fpqsort2 is a file
== fpqsort2.c
fpqsort2.c is a file
== gcc-predef.h
gcc-predef.h is a file
== git-1.6.5.7
== go
== makefile
makefile is a file
== qs-test1.c
qs-test1.c is a file
== qs-test2.c
qs-test2.c is a file
== RCS
== rep-report.txt
rep-report.txt is a file
== select.c
select.c is a file
== soq
== xx.pl
xx.pl is a file
MiniMac JL:
```

---

Given a marginally modified version of the code in the question:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;

if ($ARGV[1]) {
    die("Error: You can only monitor one directory at a time\n");
}

my $directory = $ARGV[0] || die "Error: No directory defined\n";

opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Error: Can't open dir $directory: $!";
my @contents = readdir(DIR);

foreach my $item(@contents) {
    print "<<$item>>\n";
    next if -d $item;
    print"$item is a file\n"; 
}

closedir (DIR);
```

Running it on the same directory as before, I get the output:

```
Minimac JL: perl yy.pl .
<<.>>
<<..>>
<<cproto-4.7g>>
<<fpqsort1>>
fpqsort1 is a file
<<fpqsort1.h>>
fpqsort1.h is a file
<<fpqsort2>>
fpqsort2 is a file
<<fpqsort2.c>>
fpqsort2.c is a file
<<gcc-predef.h>>
gcc-predef.h is a file
<<git-1.6.5.7>>
<<go>>
<<makefile>>
makefile is a file
<<qs-test1.c>>
qs-test1.c is a file
<<qs-test2.c>>
qs-test2.c is a file
<<RCS>>
<<rep-report.txt>>
rep-report.txt is a file
<<select.c>>
select.c is a file
<<soq>>
<<xx.pl>>
xx.pl is a file
<<yy.pl>>
yy.pl is a file
Minimac JL:
```

Note the Perlish idiom '`next if -d $item;`'.  Also note the debugging techniques: print the names as they go through the array - using the '<<' and '>>' to surround the name helps identify odd side effects (such as newlines in names).  I did double check that the provided code produces the same result - it does.  And I'm running on a MacOS X 10.6.3 with the stock Perl.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I'm passing the dir in as a arg. Would this have anything to do with it? I've placed the complete code above.

Comment: @Jonathan: Good catch..even I was testing with `.` :)

Comment: one more question, why does `"$ARGV[0]/$item"` need to be in quotes?

Comment: @Aaron: Because otherwise you're dividing $ARGV[0] by $item, and since both are likely to evaluate to 0, the system is unlikely to be happy with you.

Answer (score 3):

From the Perldoc on [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html):

> If you're planning to filetest the
>   return values out of a readdir, you'd
>   better prepend the directory in
>   question. Otherwise, because we didn't
>   chdir there, it would have been
>   testing the wrong file.

Debugged code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

if ($ARGV[1]) {
    die("Error: You can only monitor one directory at a time\n");
}

my $directory = $ARGV[0] || die "Error: No directory defined\n";

opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Error: Can't open dir $directory: $!";
my @contents = readdir(DIR);

foreach my $item (@contents) {
    print "\$item=$item\n";
    print "$item is a file \n" if (-f $directory."/".$item); 
    print"$item is a dir\n" if (-d $directory."/".$item);  
}

closedir (DIR);
```

Comment: Good quote from the perldoc page.  Isn't it a bit neater to use `"$directory/$item"` rather than `$directory."/".$item`?  Or is that just die-hard shell programmer thinking?

Comment: I thought it illustrated the prepending a bit better. I have a weakness for the `.` operator. If >>I<< were writing this, I would probably use `map` in the readdir step.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `@contents` has newlines at the end of the file. Try adding `chomp`:

```
foreach $item(@contents) {
  chomp($item);
  next if (-d $item); 
  print"$item is a file\n";       
}
```

Comment: Could be a good guess - as so often, the key information isn't in the information given in the question.  The trailing blank on '`folder 01 `' is interesting, too.

Comment: @Jonathan: Reason for guessing is if he uses a `glob` to populate `@contents` as you've done there will not be trailing newlines, but if he uses backticks: `@contents=`ls`;` there will be trailing newlines.